# Future simple in relative clauses

Tags: tense

Which sentence is correct (or both) and why:

> 1. There will be a war, which will destroy the world.
> 2. There will be a war, which destroys the world.

Answer (score 1):

Only your first sentence is correct:

- There will be a war (in the future), which will destroy the world (in the future).

The second sentence is incorrect because of the wrong sequence of tenses:

- There will be a war (in the future), which destroys the world (now or generally).